Extract values from vba data structure in Excel
I'm using the vba code in a Excel to decode Plus Codes:. The code can be found here: https://github.com/google/open-location-code/blob/main/visualbasic/OpenLocationCode.bas
This script creates a data structure as follows:
Public Type OLCArea
  LatLo As Double
  LngLo As Double
  LatHi As Double
  LngHi As Double
  LatCenter As Double
  LngCenter As Double
  CodeLength As Integer
End Type

I'm using a function that returns the result in this structure to a cell: =OLCDecode()
I'd like to extract one single value from this structure in a cell, but there is no information in the documentation and I tried to find unsuccesfuly something about to use data structures. I was thinking something like =OLCDecode(Cell).LatLo
Thanks in advance.

"I'm using a function that returns the result in this structure to a cell" - would help to include that

hi @TimWilliams Thanks for your comment. I did not write the function because I expect an answer with a generic solution to handle data structures. I edited the question to specify the function.

=OLCDecode(Cell, "LatLo") could work if you modify OLCDecode to accept an optional second parameter which could be used to determine which field of the Type to return.

Thanks for your comment @TimWilliams. There is another function that returns an array and I could handle the data. I'd like to learn if there is a method to work with this kind of structures from a cell for future projects.

There's no built-in mechanism to do what you want.
